# Android Tablet Zoom option missing

Tags: android, screen, compatibility, tablet

I've developed an android application whose GUI is designed for small screens. When run on a tablet it looks rubbish because I've assumed 320dp width to make my life easier - I don't have the resources to test on tablets.

People using android 3.2 were able to zoom into the app so it looks like it's running on a big phone. But after my last update that option is not available, and I don't understand why.

The change is related to the Manifest file. Here's what my orignal app had (there's nothing to do with screens in my Manifest):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

After updating my development environment, I got a warning saying I should specify a target sdk, so I did this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Using a painfully slow Android 3.2 emulator I have confirmed that this has caused the problem. I thought any target SDK below 11 wouldn't affect the zooming option?

Using the following also removed the zoom option:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

But this didn't:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

So setting my target SDK to 8 is a workaround, but it's also wrong because I use version 2.3.3 for testing.

Am I missing something here? Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting targetSdkVersion to 9 (or 10) **and** adding `<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml (docs for [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge)). This tells the system that your application does not explicitly support xlarge screens and that it should offer the compatibility zoom/scale option for users that use the app on xlarge devices. Note that this will **not** cause the app to be hidden from xlarge devices on the Play Store (`supports-screens` only causes Play Store to filter apps from smaller screens if they are designed to run on larger screens, not the other way around).

The reason I think this is happening once you set targetSdkVersion to 9+ is because supports-screens xlargeScreens was added in API Level 9 and (I believe) defaults to true (for API Level 9+ at least). Once xlargeScreens is true the system will disable the compatibility zoom/scale mode.

Supporting docs (where it does say this but is fairly convoluted):

- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-mode-for-apps-on-large-screens.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: I tried adding a `support-screens` item, but it wasn't recognised because my app is built against the 2.1 SDK; I think I need to build against 2.3 to use that? Could I do that and still support 2.1?

Comment: yes, you should build against the same version as targetSdkVersion. you just need to be careful you don't use any API calls from earlier versions without checking API levels first (the new Android Lint tool has a rule to help identify this).